# Visual studio 2015 use the navigation bar to switch context

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

By clicking on a certain command in my code, I get the information not available and available within my project. I do not understand how this is possible, and informs me that you can use the navigation bar to switch context, but I do not know how to do that. The attached figure shows the message. My questions are:

1. How can something be available and not avilable in the same project?
2. What is the navigation bar and how do I use it to change the context?

This is the message I received:

```
Usage:
  Dim r as list (of Streaming) = Await StartAsync(...)
   MSGEM – Available
   MSGEM – Not Available
You can use the navigation bar to wsitch context.
```

Comment: `PS: I could not post a photo, so I transcribe the message I received:`. That is what you are supposed to do anyway. Please avoid posting pictures unless absolutely necessary, especially not pictures of text!

Comment: For the navigation bar, you can see [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118895/6479770)

Answer (score 0):

This could be be down to two front-end files sharing the same back-end codefile. In such a situation, the code file will reference a front end control which is in only one of the front end files and not both.

If you do not use such a coding technique, it can easily happen accidently when making a backup of a front end code file by copying it to a different filename but forgetting to add the `.exclude` extension.

See this answer for more details:

[You can use the navigation bar to switch contex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599797/you-can-use-the-navigation-bar-to-switch-contex/46468413#46468413)