# Tests won't run in debug mode C#

Tags: c#, debugging

It was required to write a set of unit tests for a function that solves a quadratic equation. When you start debugging, this error is displayed, .NET Core has been updated to 5.0, tests have been added to the solution [enter image description here][1].

Please tell me what you can do. net5.0. IDE: Visual Studio Code. C#. Installed C# .Net Core Extension Pack (15 extensiones indispensables para programar con C# y .NET Core).

Error (translated):

> [The target process exited without raising an event fired by CoreCLR.
> Make sure the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may
> be necessary if the target process has not started in .NET Core.]

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Целевой процесс завершил работу без вызова события, запущенного CoreCLR. Убедитесь, что в целевом процессе настроено использование .NET Core. Это может быть необходимо, если целевой процесс не запускался в .NET Core.
Программа "[424] QuadEqua.dll" завершилась с кодом -2147450749 (0x80008083).
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9dWp.png

Comment: maybe ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757793/the-target-process-exited-without-raising-coreclr-started-event-error-with-net

Comment: @InUser I have VSCode :(

Comment: It doesn't matter VS Code or not. Check whether required runtime is installed

Answer (score 0):

Have you install .NET Core SDK ?
It's necessary for compile and debug with Visual Studio Code.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

Comment: It didn't help me :(

Comment: Have you a file in **.vscode** folder named `launch.json` ?
If not the case, go in the _Run and Debug_ section. VS Code ask to you to create launch file. Then, press F5.