# The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core 5.0

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have created a .Net 5 windows forms project.  It was working fine till Sep-15-2022. After that, it started throwing the following error message.
"The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[23716] CoreApp.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[23716] CoreRunQtr.exe' has exited with code -2147450740 (0x8000808c)."

So far I have tried the following and but could not get it resolved:

1. Reinstalling .NET 5 from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-5.0.408-windows-x64-installer
2. Tried the suggestions from [The target process exited without raising CoreCLR started event error with .NET Core 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757793/the-target-process-exited-without-raising-coreclr-started-event-error-with-net)

Environment:
Windows 10 64-bit OS
Visual studio 2019 Version 16.11.19

Could you please help?

Comment: .NET 5 went out of support last November. This was no surprise, as it was a short-term-support version and its expiration date was known since .NET Core 3.1 was released. You should target .NET 6, which is supported until 2024.

Comment: Beyond that, the question is unclear. If you create a new WinForms project targeting .NET Core 3.1, 5 or 6, it will work without problem, assuming the correct runtime is installed. A new machine, VM or Docker image *won't* have .NET 5 installed since it went out of support so long ago. Did you migrate to a new laptop or VM?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your quick response.  I had installed VS2022 and compiled the project without any issue.  Please note that I had to install VS2022 because .NET 6 is not compatible with VS2019.